# Создаю мини магазин в тг

Tags: javascript, массивы, веб-программирование

Проблема вот в чем , надо написать на js скрипт который будет записывать {имя товара: количество выбранного товара пользователем} (при нажатии на кнопку в корзину)
Вот html `

```
    <img class="product__img"
      src=""
      alt="Пицца">
    <div class="product__name">Пицца «Ветчина и грибы»</div>
    <div class="product__price"><span class="product__price-number">320</span> Р</div>

    <div class="product__size">

      <div class="product__size-element">52 см</div>
      <div class="product__size-element">26 см</div>
      <div class="product__size-element">16 см</div>


    </div>
    <div class="product__quantity"></div>
    <div class="number" data-step="1" data-min="1" data-max="100">
      <a href="#" class="number-minus">−</a>
      <input class="number-text" type="text" name="count" value="1">

      <a href="#" class="number-plus">+</a>
    </div>
    <button class="product__add-to-cart-button" id="btnSaveSchedule" data-sb-product-quantity="1"
      data-sb-product-img=""
      onclick="pay();" data-art="${n.name">
      <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> В корзину
    </button>
  </div> `
```

вот js
function save() {
var number; number = document.getElementById("number").value;

```js
function save() { var number; number = document.getElementById("number").value; }
```

```html
<div class="product__element">

                <img class="product__img"
                    src="https://n1s1.hsmedia.ru/4e/fa/18/4efa18fab68b54bfbe731ffed6d475ea/728x542_1_4b74ef42acac035d207606a9427e04f0@1000x745_0xac120003_11819542861578938700.jpg"
                    alt="Пицца">
                <div class="product__name">Пицца «Ветчина и грибы»</div>
                <div class="product__price"><span class="product__price-number">320</span> Р</div>

                <div class="product__size">

                    <div class="product__size-element">52 см</div>
                    <div class="product__size-element">26 см</div>
                    <div class="product__size-element">16 см</div>


                </div>
                <div class="product__quantity"></div>
                <div class="number" data-step="1" data-min="1" data-max="100">
                    <a href="#" class="number-minus">−</a>
                    <input class="number-text" type="text" name="count" value="1">

                    <a href="#" class="number-plus">+</a>
                </div>
                <button class="product__add-to-cart-button" id="btnSaveSchedule" data-sb-product-quantity="1"
                    data-sb-product-img=""
                    onclick="pay();" data-art="${n.name">
                    <i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i> В корзину
                </button>
            </div>
```

}

Comment: А что вы пробовали сделать?

Comment: Я пытался записывать нажатие в переменную , но ничего не получилось , в js я пока новичок

Comment: Когда тут спршивают "А что вы пробовали", то почти всегда имеется ввиду, чтобы в вопросе был показан код, который у вас не заработал. И мой случай не исключение :) Так что не ленимся и делимся в вопросе своими нароботками :)

Comment: function save() {
      var number;
      number = document.getElementById("number").value;
     
}

Comment: Я же попросил в вопрос добвить :) Нажимаем на кнопку Править под вопросом и добавляем так чтобы всем было видно. В вашем случае можно (и даже нужно) в редакторе вопроса нажать на CTRL + M и вставить ваш код в нужные секции, далее нажать на "Привести в порядок", запустить, избавиться от всех ненужных ошибок, убедиться что только нужная вам ошибка вопроизводится и после этого нажать на "Вставить в сообщение"

Comment: А нормально что у вас нет элемента с id `number` в коде? А ещё у вас переменная объявлена в функции, то есть вы не сможете к ней обращаться.

Comment: Для того, чтобы сделать то, что вы описали, нужно привести карточку товара в порядок, как минимум чтобы размеры пиццы можно было выбрать - сейчас это просто дивы, увеличение или уменьшение кол-ва товара работало, а еще возможно чтобы сразу сумма считалась в зависимости от количества и размера.   Поэтому порекомендую вам посмотреть вот такое видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIgyoL5FjgI. Там как раз есть все моменты которые вам нужны. Хочу сказать, это не спам и не реклама. Как-то наткнулся на него в ютубе, и вот пригодилось ))

Comment: спасибо, очень помог)